# Load post with a different template?

Tags: functions, templates, text

Let's say I have a single.php file with a certain layout (graphic intensive).  I want to create a sort of plain-text version of the same page that is only called when the user clicks the provided link.  I can create single-plaintxt.php but how would I go about generating a link and/or function that would only load the page contents using that file when clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
    //add my_print to query vars
function add_print_query_vars($vars) {
    // add my_print to the valid list of variables
    $new_vars = array('my_print');
    $vars = $new_vars + $vars;
    return $vars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_print_query_vars');
```

then add a template redirect based on that query_var:

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'my_template_redirect_2322');

// Template selection
function my_template_redirect_2322()
{
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;
    if (isset($wp->query_vars["my_print"]))
    {
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/my_print_themplate.php');
        die();

    }
}
```

create a new file in your theme directory named "my_print_themplate.php"
an paste this code there.

```
<?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    echo "<h1>printer friendly version:</h1>\n";
    query_posts('p='.$_GET['pid']);
    if (have_posts()){
        while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }else{
    echo 'nothing found';
    }
?>
```

and now all you have to do is create a link with ?my_print=$post_id in your regular single loop.

hope this helps

Comment: This is great!!!  Couple of things tho... First there's a typo, you spelled /my_print_template with an H in the function (/my_print_themplate).  No biggie, I found that easy.  Now, the only issue I'm having with this is the print function pulls several posts into the page.  I tried to limit it to by using posts_per_page to just 1 but it wasn't the correct post.  Seemed like it was the most recent post posted.  How do I pass the correct post ID variable so it is reflected in the print template?  THANKS!!!

Comment: Hello Bainternet,
very good tutorial!
Is it possible use more templates? I mean my_print_themplate.php, my_print_themplate2.php, my_print_themplate3.php. I need 5 version printable for my posts.
thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Vincent and welcome to the WPSE community. The answer box you've just used is intended **for answers only** - this is an important aspect of this site's usability.   Your post is more like a **comment** or a **question** thus it may be considered inappropriate here. Please help the site moderators and delete it from here yourself. Thanks. (You need at least **50** reputation to be able to post comments everywhere)
See: [FAQ: Why are some questions or answers removed?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) and  [FAQ: Reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 2):

I just slightly modified @Bainternet's answer.

Using a switch on post_type, it's even possible to redirect to different templates.
The default will let wordpress ignore the my_print parameter and go on as usual.

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'my_template_redirect_2322');

// Template selection
function my_template_redirect_2322()
{
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;

    if (isset($wp->query_vars["my_print"]))
    {
        switch ($wp_query->post->post_type) {
        case "page" :
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/my_print_page_themplate.php');
            die();
        case "portfolio" :
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/my_print_portfolio_themplate.php');
            die();
        case "post" :
            include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/my_print_post_themplate.php');
            die();
        default:
            // load as usual
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `die()` seems a bit harsh. `break` perhaps?

Comment: @GhostToast if you don't call `die()` after your custom `/my_print_*` template, wordpress will follow its initial route. And you'll end up with the custom template and the default template concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solution, Bainternet. It was pulling in multiple posts from the default post type as RodeoRamsay reported, so I got it to work with my custom post type like so:

```
<?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    //echo "<h1>printer friendly version:</h1>\n";
    setup_postdata($_GET['pid']); 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();

    endwhile;
?>
```